# How to add appending data to MySQL through R?

Tags: mysql, r

I am running an R script that adds data to mySQL database. I usually format the data and add it as as it comes in after couple of hours (data string is not continuous). My first set of data was added properly in MySQL database. The second string of data can not be added properly.

```
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='xxxxxx', dbname='test', host='localhost')
dbWriteTable(con, 'Tables', value = parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("lebron"), timeout=10, oauth=my_oauth)))
```

When I rerun the last code (dbWriteTable) again, it gives me following error

Error: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Table 'tables' already exists

I also used

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'Tables', value = parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("lebron"), timeout=10, oauth=my_oauth)), append = TRUE)
```

but it provides the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason giving setting append to TRUE is not working. Instead give it a number. See the code below for better understanding

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'Tables', value = parseTweets(filterStream(file.name= "", track=c("lebron"), timeout=100, oauth=my_oauth)), overwrite = 0, row.names = 0, append = 1)
```